# VaREST POST from Unreal Engine 4.25 to Postman Mock Server

Tags: rest, postman, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unrealscript

**Problem Statement:**
I have 3 objects (screen below).  Each object has a box trigger as part of the Blueprint. When the player overlaps the trigger, I want to POST to a Postman API Mock server on an ActorBeginOverlap event to change a boolean value from true to false.

**What I'm trying to Achieve:**
I have successfully created a GET request to determine if the objects should be visible or not onBeginPlay depending on the JSON value in Postman.  I need to now create a POST event on the box trigger to change the value from TRUE to FALSE.

**Where I'm running into problems:**
I'm new to Postman and vaREST so I pretty much don't know what I'm really doing and rely heavily on online tutorials. The GET request seems to have a lot of examples online but POSTS are pretty limited.  I need help getting a POST to work.

**JSON Body on Postman:**

```
{
    "id": 8675309,
    "objectives": [
        {
            "obj1": true,
            "obj2": false,
            "obj3": true
        }
    ],
    "questComplete": true,
    "reward": false
}
```

[image: 3 Blueprints]

**When Played:**
[image]

**GET Blueprint - Working Properly**
[image]

**POST Blueprint - Don't know what I'm really doing here...**
[image]